# asp:Wizard control in web part

Tags: web-part

I need to make a web part with a quiz (or exam).
Tests and questions are stored in 2 separate lists, so I want on the first step to select an exam and based on that selection I want to add steps (there are different number of steps based on exam) by code.
The problem is that after I add steps (tehere are added) and I click next at first step the steps dissapear (I think it's something with ViewState).
I can't add steps (or the whole wizard) on Init or prerender because the numeber of steps differ from exam to exam.
Any ideas ?
Thank's

Comment: I've accepted all. From now on I wii accept all. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I anticipate this issue is not related to SharePoint itself. We have asp:Wizard control in our own solution and it works like a charm.

So please ensure that your dynamic steps controls are recreated each postback.

For details, have a look at following articles:

- [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)
- [ASP.NET tips: Golden rules for Dynamic Controls](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2008/06/26/123391.aspx)